# incomplete asynctask crashes my app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using `AsyncTask` in some of my `Fragment` and `Activity` and these work nice.
But the problem is when I press back button or exit app at the time of `Asynchronous` task execution, The app crashes. This is my log cat:

```
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1327)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1338)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at me.kaidul.uhunt.MainActivity.selectItem(MainActivity.java:434)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at me.kaidul.uhunt.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:387)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at me.kaidul.uhunt.MainActivity$GetProblemListTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:680)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at me.kaidul.uhunt.MainActivity$GetProblemListTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-16 08:15:34.032: E/AndroidRuntime(21957):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not adding here the `AsyncTask` code as they are working properly without pressing back button or exiting the app. I call all the `AsyncTask` like new `GetTaskDone().execute(parameter)` and there are `onPostExecute` in every `AsycTask`.

How can I avoid app crashing ?

**Edit:**

Now I am thinking that, the problem might not in `AsyncTask`. Because my other `AsyncTask` is working regardless of backpress/exit.

This is the problematic AsyncTask:

protected class GetProblemListTask extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    if (hasConnection) {
        Date date = new Date();
        long savedTime = prefs.getLong(CommonUtils.LAST_SAVED,
                date.getTime());
        long now = date.getTime();
        if (now - savedTime > fiveDays
                || (now - savedTime <= fiveDays && prefs.getBoolean(
                        CommonUtils.problemListisCached, false) == false)) {
            if (CommonUtils.isDebuggable) {
                Log.d("updating", "need to update!");
            }
            prefs.edit()
                    .putBoolean(CommonUtils.problemListisCached, false)
                    .commit();
            isr = new JSONDownloader().getJSONStringFromUrl(params[0]);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr, bufferSize);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("problem", "in file writting");
            }
            writeToFile(sb.toString(), CommonUtils.FILE_PROBLEM_LIST);
            prefs.edit()
                    .putBoolean(CommonUtils.problemListisCached, true)
                    .commit();
            try {
                isr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (CommonUtils.isDebuggable) {
                    Log.d("isr", e.toString());
                }
            }
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (CommonUtils.isDebuggable) {
                    Log.d("br", e.toString());
                }
            }
            prefs.edit().putLong(CommonUtils.LAST_SAVED, now).commit();
        } else {
            if (CommonUtils.isDebuggable) {
                Log.d("old_copy", "Old copy is rendering");
            }
            try {
                isr = new InputStreamReader(
                        openFileInput(CommonUtils.FILE_PROBLEM_LIST));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("file_not_found", "File is missing!");
            }
        }
    } else {
        try {
            isr = new InputStreamReader(
                    openFileInput(CommonUtils.FILE_PROBLEM_LIST));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("file_not_found", "File is missing!");
        }
    }
    if (CommonUtils.isDebuggable) {
        Log.d("start", "mapping start");
    }
    try {
        isr = new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput(CommonUtils.FILE_PROBLEM_LIST));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

    }
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(isr);
    try {
        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.beginArray();
            problems.put(
                    reader.nextInt(),
                    new Problems(reader.nextString(), reader
                            .nextString(), reader.nextInt()));
            while (reader.hasNext())
                reader.skipValue();
            reader.endArray();
        }
        reader.endArray();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (CommonUtils.isDebuggable) {
            Log.d("problems", "hashmaping problem");
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 // this is selecItem() function. It's task is to add a fragment to the activity. 
    selectItem(0);
    if (CommonUtils.isDebuggable) {
        Log.d("successful", "eventually survived!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: We need to see the `AsyncTask` code to help you. It has something to do method `selectItem` in `MainActivity`. that's all I can tell you so far.

Comment: Nice catch Sir. I might get the clue. I have edited my question and add the `AsyncTask` code.Take a look!

Comment: Is selectItem posting the UI thread? If so its unnecessary. `onPostExecute` is run on the UI thread. The stack trace says line 434 in MainActivity is the source of the issue. Look at that line, its what causes the crash.

Comment: Line 434 is inside `selectItem()`. It is `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, problemSearch).commit()` (code for embedding an fragment)

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is in selectItem() because I commented this line and run. Then onbackpress, app is not crashing. Now what can I do with selectItem() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AsyncTask's `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` run on the UI thread. I'm assuming you're not retaining the instance of the AsyncTask currently and calling cancel on it in your fragment/activity's `onDestroy`.

Either add that, or add a boolean flag stating if the app is visible or not (API 17 introduced `Activity.isDestroyed()`, if you're using API level >= 17 simply use that).

Note: If you add a call to cancel the AsyncTask, you'll still need to call something along the lines of:

```
if(isCancelled()) { return; }
```

in the beginning of your `onPostExecute`.

Edit:
More complete example of the `isCancelled()` method:

In your activity:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(task != null && task.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
        task.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

And then assign task to a class-wide variable, you can simply add `task =` to the line that's doing `new AsyncTask().execute();` and it'll work exactly as it does now.

According to the documentation for [AsyncTask.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) it actually guarantees that your onPostExecute will never be called so you don't even need to do the `isCancelled()` check in there like I stated previously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using below API level 17 and according your advice, I add `if(isCancelled()) { return; }` on the beginning of every `onPostExecute`. But it is not working! The app is crashing and show almost the same logcat I have provided. Also I didn't ratain instance, I called them like new `AsyncTaskName().execute()`

Comment: @typedf using isCancelled() won't do anything if you don't actually retain the instance of the asynctask and call cancel on it. calling .execute() actually returns the AsyncTask for ease of access, so you can do `GetProblemListTask task = GetProblemListTask().execute();` then in override `onDestroy()` in your activity/fragment and call `task.cancel(true)` if the task is still running, as returned from `task.getStatus()`

Comment: @typedef I modified my answer to give more context into what I meant.

Comment: Hello, Its working! Should I do this for `AsyncTask` or only for those who has UI related work in `onPostExecute`?

Comment: @typedef Yep, that's the simplest way to do it. If you're doing long extended calls in your tasks you could also periodically check if they're cancelled during the doInBackground and bail out early if possible, in which case you can use this method to cancel the task on activity destruction even though it doesn't crash.